# bootstrap change button text size on window rezise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

need to change button font size on window resize. (using bootstrap3). 
I have menu in left side and when it's full width (240px) it looks like this:

[image]

and then i resize window, or press button to toggle the side menu it looks like this:

[image]

And I would like to change that button size and it would be enough for me.

button code is:

```
<div class="sidebar-addevent">
    <a href="#">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-addevent">+ Add event</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

and css of that button is:

```
.btn {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-addevent {
    background: #213246;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #5d95ca;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: .5s;
}
.btn-block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-addevent {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 30px 15px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Sure everything will be responsive if twitter bootstrap 3 were used.No need to add any extra css for that.  '<div class="sidebar-addevent">
    <a href="#">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-addevent">+&nbsp;Add event</button>
    </a>
</div>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i made few functions to change button css for this issue with jQuery, so here it is if someone will have similar issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    changeAddEventBtn();
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        changeAddEventBtn();
    };
    $('#minimize-sidebar').click(function(){
        changeAddEventBtnByClick();
    })      
});

function changeAddEventBtn(){
    if($('#left_menu_for_resize').width() <= 60){
        $('#add_event_btn').css('font-size', '30px');
    }else{
        $('#add_event_btn').css('font-size', '13px');
    }
}
function changeAddEventBtnByClick(){
    if($('#left_menu_for_resize').width() >= 240){
        $('#add_event_btn').css('font-size', '30px');
    }else{
        $('#add_event_btn').css('font-size', '13px');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a `button` inside an `a`, which is not valid HTML5.

Try to remove the button element and attach the button-classes to the link instead:

```
<div class="sidebar-addevent">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-addevent">+ Add event</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try to change class name as --> class="btn btn-success sq-btn fr"

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding HTML Entities and bootstrap glyphicons::

```
    <div class="sidebar-addevent">
      <a href="#">
       <button class="btn btn-block btn-addevent">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add event
       </button>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: actually not so bad idea of it, but in my case it's not suitable for this project  because of the design :)